# If dim$(W)+$ dim$(U)=$ dim$(V)$ and $W+U=V$, then $W\cap U=\{0\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I'm trying to prove the statement in the title, given that $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $W,U\leq V$ are subspaces. I know that the sum of subspaces is defined as the span of their union, so $V=$ span$(W\cup V)$. Thus the dimension of $V$ is given by a basis from $W\cup V$, implying that dim$(V)\leq|W\cup V|$. Beyond this, I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have that the sum of subspaces is the span of their union, then it should be clear enough that the dimension of the sum is the sum of the dimensions minus the basis vectors in common (meaning one is contained in the others span for example, $v_i=cw_m$, $v_i$ and $w_m$ basis vectors).

What does this look like in symbols: 
$$
\dim(V)=\dim(U+W)=\dim(U)+\dim (W)-\dim(U\cap W)
$$
now if the above is equal to $\dim(U)+\dim(W)$ can you conclude?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $W$ and $U$ have nontrivial intersection. Take a vector $v$ from the intersection, and show that there is a basis for $W$ and a basis for $U$ which both include $v$. Now take the union of those bases as a basis for $V = U+W$. This gives  dim$U$+dim$W$-1 as an upper bound for the dimension of $V$, which gives a contradiction